# Not able to update respoke sdk to 1.1.1

Tags: android

When I am trying to update by **respoke sdk** using **gradle** " compile 'com.digium.respoke:respoke-sdk:1.1.1'".

I am getting this Error:

> Failed to resolve: respoke-sdk-android:AndroidAsync:unspecified

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem with the way that the Respoke SDK was packaged for Maven in version 1.1.1. This problem has now been resolved with version 1.1.2 of the SDK, which you can use by specifying the following in your Gradle dependencies:

```
compile 'com.digium.respoke:respoke-sdk:1.1.2'
```